# PhpStorm Darcula theme colors changed

Tags: php, themes, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2021.2.3 with Darcula theme.

In the old version of PhpStorm keywords (like `function`, `class` ) were rose but now they are yellow and this is annoying to me. Is there any way to restore it to default?

Or if anyone not having this problem please export Darcula color scheme from `Settings > Editor > Color scheme`

**Old color:**
[image]

**New color:**
[image]

Comment: *"Old color:"* That's NOT Darcula **at all**. That's Monokai or similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darkola theme has changed the color scheme in the new version to improve readability; However, I was used to the previous color scheme too! I checked my settings and find another color scheme called "Monokai", which has colors similar to the photo you submitted. If this color scheme is not in your Phpstorm's settings, you can download and use it from this link:

[color scheme export file](https://filebin.net/jpsg1bgz22gsosat/Monokai.icls)